# Asked 3 questions, but received no responses; advice needed on where I'm going wrong

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, asking-questions

I'd like to get the very most I can out of the site. So far, I've had no luck with my 3 questions:

- [Issue around utc date - TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc results in date change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604487/issue-around-utc-date-timezoneinfo-converttimetoutc-results-in-date-change)
- [DataImage with comma/base64 encoded - comma disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728458/dataimage-with-comma-base64-encoded-comma-disappears)
- [Which browser prefixed allowfullscreen attributes do I need on my iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993076/iframe-allowfullscreen-attribute-what-to-use)

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I edited one of your questions, left a comment for clarification on another. I can't imagine the iframe one isn't a duplicate but I'm time limited so someone else has to search for it

Comment: No downvotes is a result!

Comment: The questions aren't bad compared to many I've seen on SO (and no down votes). Yet, I do find them too wordy,i.e., extraneous info unrelated to the problem.  I tend to click through questions that don't get to the point.

Comment: @Roberto - noted on the wordiness, its deffo something I'd suffer from, its honestly a genuine attempt to assist any prospective reader but I agree it can often be counterproductive. Will take it on board and try improve in that area.

Comment: The phrase "Issue around" is wasted space in your title. Remove it. Of course you have an issue/problem/question; that's why you're here; saying so is redundant. See here for guidance on question titles: [ask]

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett great grammar point, things "center on" and "revolve around" but "issue around" doesn't make sense at all LOL

Comment: In general, make you questions short, on point, easy to understand and easy for somebody to answer. Don't make somebody who might potentially be able to answer have to work hard to even understand your question in the first place. Walls of text get very quickly skipped over by most people. It's remarkable (and this isn't directed to the OP by any means) the number of people who expect an answer but won't do the minimum amount of work necessary to get it.

Comment: Also note, the more specific or esoteric the question, the longer you'll have to wait to find somebody with an answer. General questions get answered quickly (or closed as dupes). That's just the nature of the thing. Some times you won't get answers. So don't rely on SO for an answer - keep working the problem yourself (and answer your own question if you find a solution).

Comment: Looks like the meta effect has worked well for you - the comments seem to have resolved the problems and it would actually have been quite difficult to put together a meaningful piece of code as an answer where the comments of other pairs of eyes seem to have done the trick.

Comment: To elaborate on what @MattBurland said: keep in mind that at a certain point of proficiency and/or obscurity, odds are good that if you haven't been able to figure it out, it might not be fixable or doable. If you click through the profiles of some of the rock stars on here, you'll see that the questions THEY ask often really have no answer (what you will see is that people do try -- and try hard; what bigger feather in your cap than to answer a question from a 100K+ account?)

Answer (score 173):

Good of you to ask for feedback. Allow me to quickly assess the three questions you linked:

**[Issue around utc date - TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc results in date change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604487/issue-around-utc-date-timezoneinfo-converttimetoutc-results-in-date-change)**

It's a relatively straightforward question about some date/time conversion. Something that could be explained in two paragraphs and with five lines of code, stretches over two screens and a hundred lines of code.

The same goes for the title: most questions are about an issue, and converting datetimes generally changes some component of the datetime.

Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), cut to the chase.

---

**[DataImage with comma/base64 encoded - comma disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728458/dataimage-with-comma-base64-encoded-comma-disappears)**

Some web service that renders an equation to an image doesn't work properly, it doesn't render the comma. All other code and explanation (base64-encoding binary image data does not remove commas rendered in that image) is irrelevant.

Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), cut to the chase.

---

**[Which browser prefixed allowfullscreen attributes do I need on my iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993076/iframe-allowfullscreen-attribute-what-to-use)**

Bad title (*"Allowing an iframe to become full-screen, cross-browser"* would be a lot more useful), you say you have a "couple of examples" where it doesn't work quite properly without showing exactly how your code examples relate to the working/not working in whichever version of which browser.

---

So I see a theme: make your questions more to the point, include less code, and make sure the code you show relates to the problem you're trying to explain.

Comment: all good points. Will work on those.

Comment: This is why titles are important... they make the questions more sexy.

Comment: mmmmm sexy title

Comment: Of course somtimes that can go [too far](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/the-memes-of-arqade-and-its-chat/2196#2196)

Comment: +1 on 'Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example' for the DataImage with comma question. I read that question five times and still do not understand where in the wall of code the actual issue occurs. Include a 'problem occurs here <--' - desired outcome was 'X', actual outcome was 'Y'

Answer (score 25):

Your question [DataImage with comma/base64 encoded - comma disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728458/dataimage-with-comma-base64-encoded-comma-disappears) had no language tag (I added one).

People often use the language tag to filter questions for languages they are interested in, adding one will help your question getting noticed.

Comment: This is hugely important.  Even if I don't know enough about the language/problem to edit the body of a question, I will fix its tags to get eyeballs from people who can.